How to inject specific arguments into constructor in spring?
@Component
public class A {
    String one;
    int two;
    public A a = new ("bro",1);
    public A b = new ("come",2);

    public A(String one, int two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
}

I need to create the 2 objects in the class. How do I do this with spring using its annotations?
Should I specify any values in properties? Should I create a config class for bean creation?
Couldn't come up with solution. Please help.

just  create different bean which is subclass same  parent ,  it is very  necessary that read the spring framework doc  for you .
here is  code snippet
create bean configuation
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AConfig {

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A("bro", 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public A b() {
        return new A("come", 2);
    }
}


use case
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private A b;

    public void someMethod() {
        // Use instances of class A
        System.out.println(a.getOne()); // Output: bro
        System.out.println(a.getTwo()); // Output: 1
        System.out.println(b.getOne()); // Output: come
        System.out.println(b.getTwo()); // Output: 2
    }
}


